# C# MVC WebAPI identifying who is placing requests post successful login

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to use MVC C# WebAPIs.

What's the best way to know at the server level, who is sending you a request. For example, if I receive a login request and it authenticate, should the WebAPI return a Custom Token that the server needs to store somewhere in order to identify further calls?

If so, is the token something that the WebAPI already has embedded or is that something that I need to write?

What's the recommended way to store that token on the server? Ideally I do NOT want to use any Sessions.

Also, I'm NOT a big fan of using Membership for many reasons I won't state here.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, this will guide you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847901/is-it-possible-to-expose-multiple-endpoints-using-the-same-webapi-controller/18848495#18848495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do authentication is to used the built-in systems, but since you've already said you don't like them, you'll just have to settle for not the best way.

Regardless of whether you use membership or not, authentication works the same way in WebApi as it does in MVC and WebForms.  You use an FormsAuthentication cookie, which is automatically authenticated by the framework when the request comes in.  This is stored in the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity object.

This has not changed (much) since at least .NET 2.0, other than to improve the encryption techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an open source **MVC4 WebAPI application** that does exactly what you are describing with the token authentication. You can find it here [**WebAPISoup**](https://github.com/hylander0/WebApiSoup).

This is **Not** a asp.net membership provider. Using  a custom **DelegatingHandler**, it is simply inspecting the request headers for valid **App Id** and **Token** values and validating it against a database (EF5 Code first) before allowing the request to continue.

You configure your application to handle this globally by setting up a the handler in the **mapHttpRoute**

#### WebApiConfig.cs

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                      new HttpControllerDispatcher(config),
                      new DelegatingHandler[] { new Pipeline.AuthMessageHandler() })

        );
```

#### AuthMessageHandler

```
public class AuthMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

    private const string AppIdHeader = "AppId";
    private const string AppTokenHeader = "AppToken";
    protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> appIdValues;
        IEnumerable<string> appTokenValues;
        HttpStatusCode responseCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        Guid AppIdGuid;
        var DoesHaveAppId = request.Headers.TryGetValues(AppIdHeader, out appIdValues);
        var DoesHaveAppToken = request.Headers.TryGetValues(AppTokenHeader, out appTokenValues);
        //Forces Json to be request Body type
        request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        IPrincipal principal = null;
        if (DoesHaveAppId && DoesHaveAppToken)
        {
            if (Guid.TryParse(appIdValues.FirstOrDefault(), out AppIdGuid))
            {
                principal = ValidateAuthentication(AppIdGuid, appTokenValues.FirstOrDefault());
                if (principal != null) //Valid User
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                    if (IsAppOverLimit(AppIdGuid))
                    {
                        responseCode = (HttpStatusCode)429;
                    }
                }
                else//User failed to authenticate
                    responseCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
        }
        else//User didn't supply Key/Token
            responseCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;


        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                var response = task.Result;
                if (responseCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return response;
                else
                    return request.CreateResponse(responseCode);
            });
    }
}
```

You can find the AuthMessageHandler I have created to handle the token authentication requests [**HERE**](https://github.com/hylander0/WebApiSoup/blob/master/WebApiSoup/Pipeline/AuthMessageHandler.cs)

Comment: This looks quite something. I'll definitely download the code and will spend time on it ...thank you so much !!!